# Using SAS global variable to be called in many sql procs

Tags: sql, sas

I am very new to SAS and am struggling with how to define a global variable that can be used in many sql procs within my program

%LET seems to have a scope that is not global within my program..I'd like to declare a variable just once instead of having many %LET statements. My program has many SQL procs for different types of transaction monitoring.  For example currently i have multiple proc sqls pulling data from the same table for various instruments, but i wanted to define a threshold in which i have a static value declared, like below:

```
%let x=10000;

Proc sql;
Select trans_amount, country from transactiontable
where trans_amount > &x
And ins_type in ('C')
Quit;

Proc sql;
Select trans_amount, country from transactiontable
where trans_amount > &x
And ins_type in ('D')
Quit;

Proc sql;
Select trans_amount, country from transactiontable
where trans_amount > &x
And ins_type in ('E')
Quit;
```

Here is the error message I am getting:
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference X not resolved.
WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference X not resolved.
31                   trans_amount> &X                                                 _
                                                 22
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
              a missing value, BTRIM, INPUT, PUT, SUBSTRING, USER.

Please note Trans_amount is a numeric value derived from a sql table (numeric 8 digits).

Can some one help me or guide me to any literature that might help in declaring a variable only once instead of having to declare on %LET before every PROC sql?

I am wondering if this is SAS's way of telling me that i have a type mismatch error. Also the reason why i have to seperate the ins_type is because there is a need for seperate reports for the different ins_types.

Comment: Unless you're using macros, there's no reason the &x. should lose its value (or you're assigning  it a new value). You might need to explain more (show an example program where it occurs) to get useful advice.

Comment: If the &x is surrounded by single quotes (') then the value will not get resolved, in which case you would need to use double quotes ("). Showing the error message should also help.

Comment: Here is th error message I am getting:                                                 _
                                                 22
ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: a name, a quoted string, a numeric constant, a datetime constant, 
              a missing value, BTRIM, INPUT, PUT, SUBSTRING, USER. I am begining to wonder if this is something to do with my call for the variable. Also i need to correct myself, none of the procs work with the call for threshold_amount.

Comment: Please could you post the whole proc sql block where you're using &x?

Comment: Hi, I have made changes to the original post. Please bare with me as I am new to the forums/ coding world and especially SAS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you declare a macro variable using the %let statement, this value is stored in the global table and you do not need to declare it before every proc sql (unless the value for the macro variable x is changed locally in a proc sql step).

When you run '%let x=10000;', the macro variable x is created and will exist during your entire SAS session.

From what I gather from your error, it appears that the global statement '%let x=10000;' was not run at all during the current SAS session.

Also, if you derive a variable within the current proc sql step, you might need to use 'where where calculated trans_amount > &x;' if you apply the subsetting in the same step. (- from what I can see in your amended question, this is not necessary in this case.)

In order for your code to run, you must declare the macro variable x once in your current SAS session.

I think this should solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot kittymad, this worked, i was just running the proc without including the %let statement. My mistake.

Comment: I tried to Kitty, but apparently i require 15 reputation points, which i don't have. But thanks again for your help with this.